# SVN error “no such table: wcroot” when trying to checkout a repo

Tags: svn

I'm trying to do an initial checkout of a repository hosted on the network. The checkout fails with the error message "svn: E200030: no such table: wcroot". Googling does not seem to help. What does this error message mean, and what is the diagnosis?

My SVN binary version is 1.7.1 (r1186859).

Thanks!

(re-posted from programmers.stackexchange, as it was closed there)

Comment: Googling the last part gives me http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-dev/201007.mbox/%3C20100718151719.GE31700@daniel3.local%3E

Comment: Just happened to me and I removed 9.1 and 9.2 folder created inside the folder where I was running it. Both of those folders had wc.db file inside it and failed previously. By removing those it went through fine.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know what exactly this message means. From [this](http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2010-07/0375.shtml) i understand that there is a wc.db file created in the directory you are trying to checkout that is not initialized properly and the wcroot table is missing.

As you are doing a clean checkout, i would suggest you to check if a directory where you try to checkout already exists, if that's the case, remove it or try another directory to checkout.

In my case it was a previous `svn co` that failed and left the corrupted wc.db in the directory. So removing the directory and checking out again did the trick.

Comment: +1 - Removing the .svn folder running `svn co` again worked for me as well.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue and the problem was exact this: not enough free space on disk. This seems to override the "not enough space" message when the capacity on drive is 0 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

For me Tortoise had shut down a SQL service when it was installing. 
I rebooted, completely removed all my checkout folders and tried again without issue.

Answer (score 3):

When i tried to checkout and had this error

> sqlite[S1] no such table wcroot

I was just out of hard-disk free space on hdd target - i really had 0 byte free. There was nothing on target folder : empty, no hidden files, nothing, no previous checkouts, nor db...

And problem solved by freeing disk space

Diagnosis: hard-disk was full!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DanielKelley Does it not? He said he had the same issue, and solved it by freeing disk space. How is that not an answer?

Answer (score 2):

This happened (at least in my case) when checking out a project prom svn repository and a runtime error happened in svn client process. So I went to folder that I'm trying to check out, and removed it with "rm -Rf" command. I fixed the source of error at svn client. Then I tried agaign to check out. The problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I think I have a solution to this problem.

See if the folder has a .svn folder(which is hidden) created.

In case this .svn folder is present , delete it. Retry svn checkout. This should solve your problem.

Comment: This solution works well for any problem with wc.db corruption. Note that if you don't want to loose the local changes in the working copy, you have to checkout with the --force option, and svn will preserve the local changes.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have recently upgraded your subversion client, and the new version (1.7.x) is having problems with the wc.db file from an older version. That file, if you are on Linux, is in ~/.svn/, but simply removing it does not seem to help. Can you revert your svn client back to the older version?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that wc.db had 0bytes. I had plenty of space available, so it had to be something TortoiseSVN done. I tried to clean up the repository, but the only way how to solve this was to Checkout the repository again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused by the svn url. once there was a blank in the url,and the other was Chinese character in the url. when I corrected the url, the problem solved.You can have a try.